# Review queues are in a different order on different sites

Tags: support, review, user-interface, beta-sites

This is Politics’ review queues order in the dropdown:

[image: LQP, Suggested Edits, Close Votes, Reopen Votes, First Posts, Late Answers]

This is Science Fiction & Fantasy’s:

[image: Close Votes, Reopen Votes, LQP, Suggested Edits, First Posts, Late Answers]

[The order is the same on Mi Yodeya.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51283564#51283564)

**Why are they in a different order? Is this a bug?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are displayed in the order you unlock the queues. On regular sites you earn close/reopen voting privileges at 3,000 reputation, and that is when you gain access to those queues. You gain edit privileges at 2,000 reputation, and that gives you access to the Suggested Edits and Low Quality Posts queues.

[image: Screenshot of privileges]

> Aside from reviewing suggested edits, the low quality posts queue is also made available. This queue contains posts which were deemed of low quality by the system. Users are charged with the task of editing to improve their formatting and content, recommending deletion if it doesn't belong on our site, or marking that it is an acceptable post.
>
> ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit))

However, on Beta sites (such as Politics) the privileges don't follow that exact order. You gain close/reopen voting privileges at 500 reputation, and edit privileges at 1,000 reputation.

[image: Screenshot of privileges]

Therefore, on Beta sites the review queue list has Suggested Edits and Low Quality Posts above Close and Reopen because you gain access to them later.